# http redirect with cordova, how do I reload the page redirected to by the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cordova

I'm using cordova to deploy my server-client app.
After submitting a form, the server may redirect the client: 302 redirect and all.
In this case, the app tries to load the page from the server instead of its own memory.

I'm looking for a solution to this. To reiterate, I want the app to load the file it's being redirected to from its own file system.

What I have in mind is something like this:
I submit all forms using jquery and catch those redirects.

```
$.ajax({
    url : address,
    type : type, 
    data : values,
    statusCode: {
        302 : redirect_302
    }
})
```

And then catch the redirect and use

```
redirect_302 function(response){
    window.location = the url in the response from the server
}
```

Is that a typical solution?
Or are there better/simpler options?
Maybe I can issue the redirect in sych a way that cordova will not, by default, try to load the page from the server?

Thanks in advance.

Jenia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are to do what you are doing. Have the server return the proper redirect, unlikely since it is a file or load the file from the server.

The redirect contains a url that the application is told to use by the server so there isn't anything automatic for cordova to do.

Comment: one more quick question: how do I load the file? 
say the file is in the app file strucuture like so:
    HelloWorld--->www---->file1
How do i load it? window.location = "file:///HelloWorld/www/file1"
Or how will it look?

Comment: I would stick with relative paths as the full pathis hard to predict since different android devices handle them differently so if index is www/index and file one is www/file1 then the path would just be "file1". Just a side note i am not sure what you are redirecting but cordova works best with single page applications.